# Is there a way to calculate the needed font-size from the length in pixels the text needs to be?

Tags: powershell, fonts, bitmap

I'm writing a little fun project in which I am laying text over an image. The challenge is that literally everything except about the pieces is variable, except the font-family, which for now is Verdana.

So I get an image of unknown size, and I get a string of unknown words. Currently, I break the string into 3 separate strings, and overlay them in a bitmap over the original image, and I have gottent he font size at imgHeight/25. This has generally worked, except for when I have a really really long string, in which case the ending words of the strings get cut off.

The shortest distance from where I am to completion would be to calculate and exact font size to be a specific ratio of the image width. So my question for this sort of solution is: how can I calculate the length (in pixels) that a given string will be in a given font? From that, I can reverse it to calculate the needed font from the desired pixel length.

Another options would be to get the text to wrap in a given sized box, but I would likely still have similar problems, plus I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

Suggestions for other approaches are always welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the Windows Forms TextRenderer to calculate it?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$string = 'Example Text.'
$font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Verdana', 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]'Bold, Italic')
$size = [System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer]::MeasureText($string, $font)
$size.Width
```

Comment: Hmm. I was hoping for something more mathematical that could be algebraically flipped so that I could really use the desired length to find the font value I need. I might be able to make this work somehow, though.

Comment: I can't see a way to do that without iterating through a range of possible font sizes and checking if `width -le desiredwidth`.

Comment: Yeah. That doesn't sound very fun. I've kind of given up on that part of the project now; it was just a fun little experiment, so it's not that big of a deal. Thanks for your help and thoughts!